# React function is not getting called on selection of radio button and upload button clicked

Tags: reactjs

I want to perform Add, Replace, Remove operation on selection of radio button. I am reading data
from excel file. My add operation works but Remove and Replace function is not getting called.

I want to upload excel file, read data.

Select the Add or Remove or Replace operation by selecting the radio button.

click on the Upload button to perform the selected operation.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
    import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
    import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
    import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    
    const Upload = (props) => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState('');
      const [error, setError] = useState(false);
      const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState('')
      const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
      const [fileName, setFileName] = useState([]);
    
      const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        formControl: { margin: theme.spacing(3), },
        button: { margin: theme.spacing(1, 1, 0, 0), },
      }));
    
      const { passData } = props;
      const classes = useStyles();
    
      const handleRadioChange = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value,'event')
        setValue(event.target.value);
        setError(false);
      };
    
      const handleClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        handlingOperation(files);
        
      }
    
    
      //addOperation
    
      const addOperation = (newValue) => {
        let add = [...newValue, ...files]
        setFiles(add)
      }
         
      // //replace start
      const replaceOperation = (newValue) => {
        let results = files.map(x => {
          let el = newValue.find(y => y.NPI_ID === x.NPI_ID);
          if (el) return {
            ...x,
            PHARMACY_NAME: el.PHARMACY_NAME
          };
          return x;
        });
        console.log(results, 'results')
      }
  
    //remove start
      const removeOperation = (newValue) => {
        console.log(newValue, files, 'removeFile');
        let removeFileFilter = files.filter(x => !newValue.filter(y => y.NPI_ID === x.NPI_ID).length);
        console.log(removeFileFilter, 'removeFileFilter')
        
      }
       
      const handlingOperation = (newValue) => {
        console.log(value, 'value');
        if (value === 'Add') { 
          addOperation(newValue)
          setHelperText('File Added')
        }
        else if (value === 'Replace') {
          replaceOperation(newValue);
          setHelperText('File Replaced')
        }
        else if (value === 'Remove') {
          removeOperation(newValue);
          setHelperText('File Removed')
        }
        else {
          setHelperText('Please select an option.');
          setError(true);
        }
        passData(files)
      }
    
      const addFiles = (newfiles) => {
        newfiles.map((file) => {
          var filereader = new FileReader();
          filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          filereader.onload = (e) => {
            const bufferArray = e.target.result;
            const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });
            const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
            const wsname1 = wb.SheetNames[1];
            const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
            const ws1 = wb.Sheets[wsname1];
            let data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, ws1);
             setFiles(data);
          
          };
        });
      };
    
      const inputsHandler = (e) => {
        const file = [...e.target.files];
        addFiles(file);
        setFileName(file);
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <FormControl component="fieldset" error={error} className={classes.formControl}>
    
            <div class="title"><div>PHARMACY</div></div>
            <div class="message"> **Message <span class="messageStatus">{helperText}</span> </div>
    
            <section className="heading">
    
              <label class="custom-file-input" for="Upload" >
                <div className="combiner">
                  <span className="uploadText">Upload file </span>
                </div>
                <div className="combiner selectedFile">
                  {fileName[0] !== undefined ?
                    <span className="fileName">{fileName[0].name}</span>
                    : null
                  }
                  <input type="file" name="file" id="Upload" className="input-field" accept=".csv, .xlsx,.xls,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
                    onChange={inputsHandler}
                    multiple
                  />
                </div>
              </label>
    
            </section>
    
            <div className="radioTitle">Upload a file to:</div>
            <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={value} onChange={handleRadioChange}>
              <FormControlLabel value="Add" control={<Radio />} label="Add" />
              <FormControlLabel value="Replace" control={<Radio />} label="Replace" />
              <FormControlLabel value="Remove" control={<Radio />} label="Remove" />
    
            </RadioGroup>
    
            <div className="buttonParent">
              <Button type="button"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.button}
                onClick={(e) => { handleClick(e) }} > Upload  </Button>
    
            </div>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default Upload;
```

Comment: Is your `value` is correct on changing the radion button?

Comment: @SwarajGandhi, Yes the handlingOperation function is showing the value as Add, Replace, Remove in the console

Comment: In your remove and replace functions, you are not updating the state

Comment: She is saying it's not getting called, right? @RashmiUI

Comment: @ImanpalSingh, In the addOperation function I am changing the  state in setFiles(add) and in the handlingOperation function calling the addOperation